# Updating SQL Server table using values from List<> C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've been trying to update a column on a table with a result of a calculation that's been stored on a List<>.The problem is, the data saved from the List are only the first index, and the data saved are only from the first index of the List. Here's the code:

```
private void UpdateStatus()
    {
        sqlcon = con.ConnectSQL();
        List<string> statusList = DetermineStatus();
        for (int i = 0; i < statusList.Count; i++)
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            string sql = "update Table set Status= @status where Status is null";
            SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlcon);
            using (sqlcom)
            {
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", statusList[i]));
                sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            sqlcon.Close();
        }
    }
```

I'm sorry if this is kinda stupid question, also I'm sorry for the not proper English as English is not my first language. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I suppose I didn't clarify what I wanted to do earlier. So, the code is supposed to run after I've run an import of an xls attendance data. Because the data only contains the time of entry and exit on separate row, I've been making the data to be re-arranged and whether the employee worked full-time or not.

Let me illustrate it for you.

Here's what the table looked like in the database.

```
Date | TimeIn | TimeOut | ID | Status
```

For the xls data, it is structured like this:

```
EventTime | ID | Name | Function
```

In a work day, an employee is supposed to register their attendance twice, once for getting in, and once for getting out and whether they're getting in or out is determined by the Function column. In essence, what I'm trying to do is this: Import the xls data, put the data to its corresponding column in the database, and determine whether the employee worked a full day or not by comparing the time of entry and exit and putting the result in a List. The reason I've used `is null` on the clause is after importing the new data is the only ones without data on the `Status` column.

So, the problem I've been getting is the data on the table is being updated by the first index of the List.

For example, if an employee worked full time on the first day and didn't on the next. The status column on the first row should be `Full Day` and next one `not Full Day`, but I've been getting `Full Day` on both rows.

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does the content of the list correspond to? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: `SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlcon);` wrap this in a using as well also the sql.Open() is all you need you don't need to explicitly call sql.Close(); since you are inside a using .. also show us what the List looks like change the for loop to a foreach loop since you are working against a collection.. something like `foreach(var s in statusList)` and if you are using primary keys in the database how are you matching them to the values being updated from the list? this will therefore update everything.. read up on Sql Update statements

Comment: @YakoubMassad I've edited the question for more clarity, I hope it is clear enough for you.

Comment: @MethodMan I've tried using a foreach and while loop and the results is pretty much the same. Please check the my revised question if it helped you understand the question more clearly or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your first UPDATE will change the Status for EVERY row where the Status is null.  After that, since no row has a status of null, no other row can be updated with the other values.

What you need to do is to add a second parameter for your WHERE clause that also matches to your primary key--and since you did not provide your table structure,  nor for what values are in your List, we can't help any further.

Comment: Thank you, I realized that after the first run of the UPDATE command, all the rows are updated and next command will not be executed becaused WHERE clause isn't fulfilled. I've added another clause to the update command to rectify the error.